# codeigniter redirect to another directory view

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

How can I redirect to another directory view 
I have two directories in views directory as

```
views->
     public->
          login.php
      admin->
           admin_panel.php
```

in the controller, I want to redirect page if successful then

admin->adminpanel.php
else
public->login

```
if($this->form_validation->run()){

    $this->load->view('admin/admin_panel');

}
else{
        $this->load->view('public/admin_login');
}
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: actually problem is that header and footer files are in public folder how to get it in admin/admin_panel.php  <?php include('public/public_header.php');?>

Comment: oh but that's not evident in the question at all. Please modify the question. you can use ../public/public_header.php but if it's common to all pages, i'd rather put it directly under views or inside a common folder under views shared by all the views subfolders.

Comment: but ../public/public_header.php is not opeining   Message: include(): Failed opening '../public/public_header.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR')

Comment: You can use multiple **$this->load->view();**. [multiple views on codeigniter](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#loading-multiple-views)

Comment: where are you putting the include statement?

Comment: thanks for your help I learn new thing today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I place header and footer inside admin_panel.php

admin->admin_panel.php

```
<?php include('../public/public_header.php');?>

<h5 class="lead">Admin Panel</h5>
<?php include('../public/public_footer.php');?>
```

now I remove the header and footer line from above file
and put this in Controller file

```
if($this->form_validation->run()){
    $this->load->view('public/public_header');
    $this->load->view('admin/admin_panel');
    $this->load->view('public/public_footer');
}else{
    $this->load->view('public/admin_login');
}
```

Comment: but this will add header and footer twice each

Comment: could you please tell me how @inarilo

Comment: Use just one of the methods. Right now you are adding the header and footer inside the view file as well as in the controller.

Comment: You'r​ right in view file it won't work so that I wrote inside controller only

Comment: Instead of using include to load a view with in view you can use `<?php $this->load->view('someview');?>` this does the same when want to load view with in view.

Answer (score 2):

You would do something like:

```
if($this->form_validation->run()){
    // redirect to admin panel controller
    redirect('admin/admin_panel', 'refresh');
}

// load this pages views
$this->load->view('public/header_view');
$this->load->view('public/admin_login_view');
$this->load->view('public/footer_view');
```

The redirect stops execution of the current controller so no need for an else statement here.

You should only code your header or footer or any common block once (except your admin panel will probably have it's own different header view file). You can then chain your load view calls to create a page of any layout re using blocks used on other pages if required.

The 'refresh' in the redirect just means that the url will also change as if the user had actually clicked a link with that url on it. Without it the original form_post url will show.

Hope that helps,

Paul.